# Selection of points based on position

Tags: list-manipulation, conditional, envelope

I have a series of points, for example:

```
points = {{0, 0}, {1, 3}, {2.5, 2.5}, {4, 4}, {6, 6}};
```

I want to join all points successively unless, for example, the y-coordinate of 2 is bigger than 1, i.e. all points remain either on or above the line. If this situation occurs I want the line to go straight from 1 to 3. See the picture:
[image]

I have used `MapThread` for the y-coordinate

```
a = Drop[points, -1][[1 ;;, 2]];
b = Drop[points, 1][[1 ;;, 2]];
ff = MapThread[#1 > #2 &, {a, b}]
```

and tried the following if statement

```
If[# === True, Table[{x[[i]], x[[i + 1]]},
     {i, 1, Length[x] - 1}] , Table[{x[[i]], x[[i + 2]]},
     {i, 1, Length[x] - 2}] ] & /@ ff
condition[points]
```

This does not work. Could you suggest how I can get the the solution I am looking for?

The list I am actually working on is the following:

```
contour = {{3.539558864066798`, 4.`}, {3.5395588640667976`, 
    3.4604411359332024`}, {3.543141897698865`, 
    3.`}, {3.5431418976988645`, 
    2.4568581023011355`}, {3.316938473746351`, 
    2.`}, {3.316938473746352`, 1.6830615262536484`}, {3.`, 
    1.2230083822966231`}, {2.9010374808950017`, 
    1.0989625191049983`}, {2.549025177579707`, 
    1.`}, {2.241373141469883`, 0.7586268585301169`}, {2.`, 
    0.7040937888965587`}, {1.7398311979371794`, 1.`}, {1.`, 
    1.7438435212932406`}, {0.862986014916355`, 
    2.`}, {0.862986014916355`, 
    2.137013985083645`}, {0.356666562092694`, 
    3.`}, {0.356666562092694`, 
    3.643333437907306`}, {0.13375920808029088`, 4.`}};
```

And the line I want to be able to plot is
[image]

I want to be able to join the first and last elements of the list with a line that either includes or leaves all points above it so it never crosses the black line.

Comment: "distance between point 1-3 is shorter than 1-2-3". According to the Triangle inequality, this is always the case.

Comment: You seem to be working too hard. For instance, would it not be better to write `distanceNorm[pts_] := EuclideanDistance @@@ Partition[pts, 2, 1]`? Then 
with `pts = {{0, 0}, {1, 3}, {2.5, 2.5}, {4, 4}, {6, 6}}`, `distanceNorm[pts]` gives `{Sqrt[10], 1.58114, 2.12132, 2 Sqrt[2]}`. Is this not the same a what you get from your more prolix definition?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

### Update

Following your updated and clarified question I believe you are looking for a [convex hull](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Convex_hull) or something very closely related to it.  Using the new-in-10.0 functionality for your data we have:

```
hull = ConvexHullMesh[contour];

line = RegionPlot[hull][[1, 1]];

ListLinePlot[{contour, line}]
```

[image]

A look at the hull itself from which I extracted the points:

```
Graphics[{Red, Polygon[contour], First @ RegionPlot @ hull}]
```

[image]

The points plotted are:

```
line
```

> ```
> {{3.53956, 4.}, {3.54314, 3.}, {3.54314, 2.45686}, {3.31694, 1.68306},
>  {3., 1.22301}, {2.90104, 1.09896}, {2.24137, 0.758627}, {2., 0.704094},
>  {1., 1.74384}, {0.862986, 2.}, {0.356667, 3.}, {0.133759, 4.}}
> ```

---

#### Original interpretation

I first posted a broken method.  Here is a second attempt.  It will be horribly inefficient on long lists but I think it at least works as I intend.  I shall try to improve it tomorrow.

```
SeedRandom[423]
points = RandomInteger[99, {30, 2}] // Sort;

points //. {a___, q : {_, y1_}, r : {_, y2_}, s : {_, y3_}, b___} /; 
    y2 >= y1 && y3 <= y2 :> {a, q, s, b};

ListLinePlot[{points, %}]
```

[image]

Comment: Why cannot be [this](http://o8aucf9ny.bkt.clouddn.com/2016-06-18-04-31-28.png) ?Or maybe I miss something.

Comment: @yode I don't know, I just interpreted it differently.  I guess we need clarification from GEF.  +1 on your answer in any case.

Comment: @yode thank you for introducing me to the 2 new functions. The `PeakDetect` function is very close to what I want to achieve. However, what @ Mr.Wizard♦ has posted is even closer. I wan the line to join the first and last points in the list. The line must have the minimum length possible and with the data you are using should look like this ![Valid XHTML](https://www.dropbox.com/s/ucigoespkjh5g9y/Untitled.jpg?dl=0).

Comment: @GEF Thanks for clarifying your question.  As you can see I have reopened it.

Comment: Upvote,Impressive your `RegionPlot[hull][[1, 1]]`

Comment: @ Mr.Wizard♦ Amazing! `ConvexHullMesh` works very well, thank you!

Comment: @GEF You're welcome, and I am glad I could help.

Answer (score 4):

Well,just introduce two function to you.Maybe both not what you want exactly.

```
SeedRandom[423]
points=RandomInteger[99,{30,2}]//Sort;
```

## PeakDetect

```
ListLinePlot[{points,DeleteCases[points PeakDetect[-points[[All,-1]]],{0,0}]}]
```

[image]

## MinDetect

```
ListLinePlot[{points,DeleteCases[points MinDetect[points[[All,-1]]],{0,0}]}]
```

[image]